# How to assign a 1 or a 2 based on several criteria (interesting puzzle)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an interesting puzzle. What I am trying to assign a 1 or a 2 based on the several criteria:

1. 2 get assigned to the highest values
2. 1 gets assigned to the lowest values
3. the 1's and the 2's have to add up to 64.

I have a data set that has 50 variables. It kind of looks like this

```
x    y    z
50  100
49  97
... ...
1   40
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is column Z, assign a 1 or a 2. This chart is sorted so the values in Y are from highest to lowest. I need to assign a 2 to the highest values in column Y (and 1 for the lowest values). However, I need the 1's and 2's to sum up to 64.

I have been stuck for a while on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy with a macro.

Begin by assigning 1 to every item.  Then, starting with the highest value and working your way down, add 1 to the items until the total reaches 64.

```
Sub assign_values()
    Range("C1:C50").Value = 1
    For i = 1 To 50
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C:C")) = 64 Then Exit Sub
        Cells(i, "C").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Note that my data has been sorted high-to-low and the code takes advantage of that.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly, make a column that has a 1 in it. Run this macro and it will add +1 to the cells starting from top to bottom until the sum of the column equals 64?

Comment: @GCC  The macro I coded puts an initial ***1*** in each cell.

Comment: @GCC you don't need to make another column with 1s the code will do that for you on column C.

Comment: Thanks for you help. This almost worked the way I needed it to. There are a couple other things I need. If there is a value that is equal to or less than 0, I need it to assign 0 to it and still have the 1's and 2's equal to 64. Also, how do I keep the loop going for the next 50 rows of data and so forth?

Comment: @GCC  I would need to see all your data to answer the additional questions.

Comment: @GCC once you get an answer to the question posed please do not change the requirements.  Try to modify the answers given to suit your needs.  If you are unable, ask a new question linking back to this one showing what you have tried to answer your own question and where it fails.

Comment: Sorry about the extra requirements. I will create a new question.

Comment: @GCC  **No need to be sorry.**  Sometimes its a good thing to solve a simple version of a problem before moving ahead with the full problem..........at least you get a framework  to expand.

Answer (score 3):

There have to be 14 "2"s and 36 "1"s.

You could rephrase your problem this way:

1. `x` is the number of rows assigned a 2
2. `y` is the number of rows assigned a 1
3. 2x + y = 64
4. x + y = 50
5. Solve for x and y.

Comment: So based on that logic put this in Z2, assuming X2 is the 50: `IF(Y2>=LARGE($Y$2:$Y$51,14),2,1)`

Comment: Assuming the data in Y is not sorted large to small.  If it is then `=IF(Row(1:1)<=14,2,1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah up to OP - my point was more that "you can figure out the answer with simple math" :)

Comment: I get that I was just building on your answer with the formulas that would return what is wanted by the OP.  I was not questioning the validity of this answer as it is sound.

Comment: I love the algebraic approach you used.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like this?

```
=1+1*(ROW(C1)<=64-COUNTA($B$1:$B$50))
```

EDIT: if you want the column length to be also variable and still give you 64 on Z sum, you can just use a if:

```
=IF(B1<>"";1+1*(ROW(C1)<=64-COUNTA(B:B));"")
```

Just change the semicolon for commas if your Excel need to

Comment: I don't understand, guy doesn't even reply me even if I was the first to solve as tagged with Excel Formula